# Separating JSON contents in to columns and exporting as an excel

Tags: python, json, excel

I am facing an issue with converting Json file content in to excel. The below is the code , I wrote so far in python

```
import json
with open(r'C:\Users\xsd\Downloads\gen_elec_sl.ec.results.2020.json') as fcc_file:
    fcc_data = json.load(fcc_file)
    print(fcc_data)
```

the output is like,

```
[{'type': 'RE_VI', 'timestamp': 1596726360, 'level': 'ELECTORAL-DISTRICT', 'ed_code': '07', 'ed_name': 'Galle', 'by_party': [{'vote_count': 120209, 'vote_percentage': '66.08%', 'seat_count': 0, 'national_list_seat_count': 0, 'party_code': 'SLPP', 'party_name': 'Sri Lanka Podujana Peramuna'}, {'vote_count': 38157, 'vote_percentage': '20.98%', 'seat_count': 0, 'national_list_seat_count': 0, 'party_code': 'SJB', 'party_name': 'Samagi Jana Balawegaya'}, {'vote_count': 11071, 'vote_percentage': '6.09%', 'seat_count': 0, 'national_list_seat_count': 0, 'party_code': 'JJB', 'party_name': 'Jathika Jana Balawegaya'}, {'vote_count': 7903, 'vote_percentage': '4.34%', 'seat_count': 0, 'national_list_seat_count': 0, 'party_code': 'UNP', 'party_name': 'United National Party'}, {'vote_count': 1912, 'vote_percentage': '1.05%', 'seat_count': 0, 'national_list_seat_count': 0, 'party_code': 'OPPP', 'party_name': 'Our Power of People Party'}, {'vote_count': 826, 'vote_percentage': '0.45%', 'seat_count': 0, 'national_list_seat_c
```

So the excel columns need to be "    type,timestamp,level,ed_code,ed_name,vote_count,vote_percentage,seat_count,national_list_seat_count,party_code,party_name"

If you need to download the file, just go to https://results.elections.gov.lk/ link and click on the fist link saying Download results as JSON.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: What types of solutions have you tried?

Comment: @Chris , I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692923/converting-pandas-json-rows-into-separate-columns thread.  but cannot apply this to this scenario..

Comment: You may give it a try with Excel PowerQuery to directly upload a JSON into Excel where you can see the result of each step of the ETL. On the ribbon bar, choose: Data > Get Data > From File > From Json

Comment: In Python you may want to upload the json into a pandas data frame. (The link you mentioned starts with having such a pandas data frame.)

Comment: @Anonymous thanks. yes i tried with excel, but it does open with separate links. cannot export it in to excel. Can you help me with that in python? im really new to it...

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/json